# Invoking a WebAPI from a WCF client

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api

I have a WCF service in production that was built few years back. I am rewriting it to WebAPI, is there an easier way for my clients(wcf clients, these are external) to consume the API without having to rewrite client code. I am thinking along the lines of changing base address in the WCF proxy.

Comment: If they are using a protocol not supported by WebAPI, im afraid they may need to change.

Comment: As long as we don't create restful-style services through WCF, I think the way our clients invoke the service needs to change. 
Because in the case of Restful-style services, we invoke them by sending HTTP requests, and for SOAP services created through WCF, most of the people call the service by generating the client proxy class, instead of sending services by constructing HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

WCF supports a number of transport protocols, not just HTTP. So if the service uses a non-HTTP transport (TCP, Named Pipes) the clients will have to be rewritten to reflect that. Unfortunately the chances are that they will also need to be rewritten even if the WCF service was HTTP-based. Most WCF HTTP services use SOAP and are thus XML-based. Web API services should be RESTful and typically use JSON as the message format, although XML is also supported. Even if both services use XML as the message format the fact that the WCF service clients probably produced SOAP message would mean that you would have to do a lot of work deserializing and serializing the XML in a Web API environment in order to avoid having to rewrite the clients (and lose much of the value in moving to Web API). The bottom line is that given the probability that the respective message formats will be different you will have to rewrite the clients.